# Find length of string in C (without using strlen)

Tags: c

The code below does not print anything -

```
int main() {

        char *input = "This is a string";
        find_length(input);
        return 0;

}
void find_length(char *input){

    printf("%s", input);
    int length = 0;
    while(input[length]!='\0');
    {
        length++;
        printf("%i", length);
    }

}
```

Comment: try initializing as so: char *input = "This is a string\0";

Comment: codemaniac, string literals in C always are null-terminated.

Comment: Just an extra semicolon after while loop. Also check it here for beginners [C program to find length of string](http://www.codeforwin.in/2015/04/c-program-to-calculate-length-of-string.html).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**You have an extra semicolon behind your loop:**

```
while(input[length]!='\0');
                          ^ does not belong here!!!
```

So it is stuck in an infinite loop. Get rid of it.

---

**Furthermore, there could be stream buffering.** Try adding some `\n`. Or call `fflush(stdout)` to flush the output stream.

```
void find_length(char *input){

    printf("%s\n", input);
    int length = 0;
    while(input[length]!='\0')  //  remove ;
    {
        length++;
        printf("%i\n", length);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does, but since it does not print a newline the buffer doesn't get flushed until the program exits, and you will end up with a shell prompt on the same line.  Some people have shell prompts with carriage returns, which would overwrite the program output.

Change this:

```
printf("...", ...);
```

To this:

```
printf("...\n", ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 char str[100];
 printf("Enter a string: ");
 printf( "\rLength is: %d", printf("Entered string is: %s\n", gets(str)) - 20);
 return 0;
}
```

In the above program, gets() returns the entered string. We print the length using the first printf. The second printf() calls gets() and prints the entered string using returned value of gets(), it also prints 20 extra characters for printing “Entered string is: ” and “\n”. That is why we subtract 20 from the returned value of second printf and get the length.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `for(int i=0; str[i];i++)` this loop also runs as long as the elements inside array of characters are true not `'\0'`. Which you can count it until `'\0`.
In the code below you can see the same thing with `while` loop but when you return you should do `-1` as when loop encounters `'\0'` it terminates but it also adds `1`. If this confuses you, you can use same logic with `for(length=0; ch[length];length++);` then you don't have to do `-1`;

```
                #include <stdio.h>

                int strlength(char ch[]){
                    int length =0;
                    while(ch[length++]);
                    return length-1;
                }


                int main(){

                    char ch[20];
                    scanf("%s", ch);
                    // printf("%s", ch);
                    printf("%i\n",strlength(ch));
                    return 0;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Increment the `length` variable or remove semi-colon to while loop.

Try,

```
void find_length(char *input){
    int length = 0; /* declaration */

    printf("%s", input);
    while(input[length++]!='\0');
    printf("%i", length);
 }
 /* OR */
 void find_length(char *input){
    int length = 0;
    while(input[length]!='\0') 
    {
     length++;
     }
    printf("%i", length);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the other posts will point you to the right answer.

But I just want to drop one note here. It would be good if `find_length()` return the length of the string (`size_t` or it could also be `int`) instead of `void`

OTOH, you can look at the various other implementation of `strlen()`. Hope it helps!

```
#include <stdio.h>

// array version
int strlen1(char a[])
{
        int len = 0;
        while (a[len])
                len++;
        return len;
}

// pointer version
// *p++ = dereference the pointer value and then
// increment the pointer to the next memory location
int strlen2(char *p)
{
        int len = 0;
        while (*p++)
                len++;
        return len;

        /*              
        int *q = p;
        while (*p);
                p++;
        return p-q;
        */
}

int main()
{
        char s[] = "test string";
        char *p = "another string";

        printf("strlen1(%s) = %d \n", s, strlen1(s));
        printf("strlen1(%s) = %d \n", p, strlen1(p));

        printf("strlen2(%s) = %d \n", s, strlen2(s));
        printf("strlen2(%s) = %d \n", p, strlen2(p));

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to find Length of the given string

```
int strLength(const char *_array)
  {
     int str_len=0;
        while(*(_array++))  
          str_len++;

        return str_len;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer: (len will be lenght of string, string is the string!)

```
int len;
for(len=0; string[len]!='\0'; len++);
printf("Length of string is %i", len);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but...why are you bothering on creating a loop to get the length of the string as already `printf` can do that via the specifier `%n`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *input = "This is a string";
    int length=0;
    printf("%s%n",input,&length);
    printf("\nThe length of \"%s\" is %d",input, length);
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can even get the output of the `printf` function after printing the string like that:

```
length=printf("%s",input);
printf("\nThe length of \"%s\" is %d",input, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
C++, Count string without functions

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string leng;
    cout << "Enter String for Count" << endl;
    cin >> leng;
    int a = 0;
    while (leng[a++]);
    {
    cout << a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use of `strlen` source instead `strlen`
Gnu C Compiler - GLIBC

```c
#include <string.h>

size_t strlen (const char *str)
{
  int cnt;

  asm("cld\n"           /* Search forward.  */
      /* Some old versions of gas need `repne' instead of `repnz'.  */
      "repnz\n"         /* Look for a zero byte.  */
      "scasb" /* %0, %1, %3 */ :
      "=c" (cnt) : "D" (str), "0" (-1), "a" (0));

  return -2 - cnt;
}
```

note **`asm`** used to insert assembly in C source (also it's may be `__asm__`)

Answer (score -2):

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *input = "Enter Any string";
    printf("your Entered String is: %s\n", input);

    int length = 0;
    while (input[length] != '\0') {
          length++;
    }

    printf("length is : %i\n", length); 
}
```

Comment: Please mention why have you posted this code as answer? and how it helps user to solve his issue?